# UAC: сохранение привелегий после перезагрузки

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uac

Предположим, есть некая программа, например, антивирус, который был установлен в систему. Ему были выданы права при первом запуске, но немного позже компьютер был перезагружен. Но антивирус, несмотря на это, сохраняет свои привелегии и имеет доступ к защищённым частям системы.
Каким образом антивирусу удается сохранять свои привилегии? Возможно ли подобное реализовать в своём C# приложении?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону служб Windows

Comment: Та же самая проблема: после перезагрузки служба не имеет повышенных прав.

Comment: Добавлю еще то, что служба устанавливается в аккаунт `LocalSystem`, а такие службы, судя по [документации]([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx), имеют права администратора. Но мне все же не удается выполнять какие-либо действия, требующие повышенные привилегии.

Comment: Не бывает так. Вы как-то неправильно службу ставите...

Comment: Ну, кажется, как-то неправильно поставить службу достаточно сложно... Впрочем, подобное явление могло быть вызвано тем, что я использовал класс `ManagedInstallerClass`, но вряд ли. 
_Только сейчас заметил, что накосячил с ссылкой в комментарии выше :/_